# Separating 2 chemicals

Tags: organic-chemistry, extraction, separation-techniques

Is it possible to  separate two chemicals with slightly different melting points? Can this be done with the use of a lab freezer? As MP is -44 and The other is -61 - -59 °C.

Will it solidify these two substances separately? Or each becoming a separate layer?

Comment: Depends, see: [Eutectic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eutectic_system)

Answer (score 2):

The process of separating chemicals by their melting points is called [fractional freezing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_freezing). In [zone refining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_melting), it is used to produce some of the most pure chemicals, for example [Si 99.999999999% (11N, meaning 11 *9*'s) pure](https://slideplayer.com/slide/10733990/).

However, your question *per se* is **far** too general to be answered. Some substances can be more easily separated than others. For example, an attempt [to separate $\ce{DHO}$ and $\ce{D2O}$ from $\ce{H2O}$](http://www.fusor.net/board/viewtopic.php?t=6962) did not succeed under the test conditions.

Comment: Physicochemical Information of unwanted chemical is
Boiling point 119 - 121 °C (1013 hPa)
Density 0.913 g/cm3 (20 °C)
Explosion limit 1.8 %(V)
Flash point 18 °C
Ignition temperature 329 °C
Melting Point -61 - -59 °C
Vapor pressure 21.3 hPa (20 °C)
Solubility 5.1 g/l.

Comment: And the desired in is. 
Molar mass
86.09 g·mol−1
Appearance
Colorless liquid
Density
1.1286 g/mL (15 °C), 1.1296 g/mL (20 °C)
Melting point
−43.53 °C (−46.35 °F; 229.62 K)
Boiling point
204 °C (399 °F; 477 K)
log P
-0.76[3]
Acidity (pKa)
4.5
Refractive index (nD)
1.435, 1.4341 (20 °C)
Viscosity
1.7 cp (25 °C

Comment: What if I buy a HPLC Chromatography machine. Will this work?

Comment: With the difference in boiling points you quote (120C  v 204C) distillation loooks a good bet.